# LD cannot find lib even with specified path

Tags: compiling, gcc, ffmpeg

What I've tried:

- gcc -L/path/to/lib/ -llib ...
- gcc -l/path/to/lib/lib.so.x.x.x ...
- Update ldconfig
- Added path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- `file` shows correct build version and link to the correct file

No matter what, I still get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavfilter`

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a `libavfilter.so` (with no numbers) anywhere? You probably need the `avfilter` development package (`libavfilter-dev` on Debian and derivatives).

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. I'm not quite sure why though, since I already had the libraries in that particular directory.
libavfilter.so is in the same folder as *.so.x.x.x, which it links to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ld` looks for shared libraries or linker scripts named `libsomething.so`, or static libraries named `libsomething.a`, where `something` matches the `-lsomething` parameter given to `ld`. Libraries named `libsomething.so.x.y.z`, where `x.y.z` is the library’s version, are used at runtime, not for building, and `ld` won’t use them.

You therefore need to install the development packages for libraries you want to link to, such as `libavfilter-dev` in your case (assuming Debian or a derivative).